# Get a title of a page loaded with .load

Tags: jquery

I load content of the page at a clicked link's `href` using `.load()`, like the following:

```
$("html").on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // obviously
    var url = this.href + " #main"; // holds the content of #main at a given url
    $('#ajax-container').load(url); // loads that content into #ajax-container
    document.title = "?";
});
```

How can I grab the title of the loaded page and display it?

Comment: `$('title').html()` or `$('title').text()` should do it

Comment: If you are loading just the content in `#main`, the returned data will not contain the `<title>` element (unless you have it inside `#main`) - which means most likely you will not be able to get it the way you are doing it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this maybe:

```
var url = this.href; //following techfoobar's comment

$('#ajax-container').load(url,function(data){
    document.title = $($.trim(data)).find('title').text();//$.trim() used for old IE to move unexpected characters
});
```

But then, you won't gat what you expect as content in `$('#ajax-container')`

So use $.get() instead:

```
var url = this.href; //following techfoobar's comment

$.get(url,function(data){
     document.title = $('<div/>').html($.trim(data)).find('title').text();
     $('#ajax-container').html($('<div/>').html($.trim(data)).find('body').html());
});
```

Comment: Hi @roasted. Tried it, nothing's happenin'.

Comment: Hang on, @roasted, you're using `url = this.href`, without `+ " #main"` - wouldn't load the entire html  into `#ajax-container` ?